# Preventing to start a new page with the temporary change to landscape mode

Tags: page-breaking, landscape

When I use

[image]

When I insert a picture with landscape mode, the new page break is introduced to make a big blank. Can I prevent this?

```
\section{A}
\label{sec:flow-data-through}

Figure \ref{df} shows the data flow diagram of \system. 

<-- New page begins     

\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{fig/flow.pdf}
  \caption{The flow of data through the system}
\lable{df}
\end{figure}

abcdef
```

Comment: I see no command to go in landscape mode.

Comment: User \rotatebox instead of landscape.  (What egreg said.)

Comment: Look for `\afterpage` in the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sideway seems to be working.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{sideways}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textheight]{fig/ds.pdf}
\end{sideways}
\caption{…}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```